# Unable to query ApplicationDbContext, method takes 1 argument

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I am trying to get a list of models but I can't seem to Query the ApplicationDbContext.I am getting a **No overload for method 'Query' takes 1 arguments. 
Here my ApplicationDbContext

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public DapperController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

and the GetAll method

```
public List<PoleModel> GetAll()
        {
            var obj = _context.Query<PoleModel>("Select * from dbo.GRAD").ToList();
            return obj;
        }
```

Should I use something other then List? Like IEnumerable or something? I am a bit lost as I've not worked in .NET Core before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use a mix up of Entity Framework and Dapper. You're injecting an ApplicationDbContext, but then trying to query it with Dapper as you would a SqlConnection object instead.

To query the context with EF, you'd do something like:

```
public List<PoleModel> GetAll()
{
    var obj = _context.PoleModelDbSet.ToList();
    return obj;
}
```

Whereas to use Dapper, you'd inject a SqlConnection, something like:

```
private readonly SqlConnection _connection;
public DapperController(SqlConnection connection)
{
    _connection = connection;
}
```

and query it something like:

```
public List<PoleModel> GetAll()
{
    var obj = _connection.Query<PoleModel>("Select * from dbo.GRAD").ToList();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you John, that was what I needed. I also learned that the lack of sleeps makes me rather dumb :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable migrations for your code first database to initialize. Open package manager and type in:

1. Enable-migrations
2. Add migration initCreate
3. Update database